# Can I change the templating engine in Typeahead.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

Twitter Typeahead.js 0.10.0 now uses Bloodhound.js to interact with the server.

Is it possible to change the templating engine it uses from handlebars to underscore.js' or knockout.js punches' templating engine?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Oh, I was blind to the obvious. In configuring twitter typeahead, in the **templates** option, in **suggestion** sub-option; there you can pick your view engine. To illustrate (taken from http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/):

```
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'twitter-oss',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: repos.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
      '<p class="repo-language">{{language}}</p>',
      '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',
      '<p class="repo-description">{{description}}</p>'
    ].join(''))
  }
});
```

The code above uses Handlebars. But you can use any templating engine that supports **compile** function. The **compile function takes the user template and processes it as need be to get the HTML that needs to be rendered. If you want to use underscore, extend it to support a function called "compile" and reference that.** The code illustrating this is below.

```
;(function (_) {
    'use strict';

    _.compile = function (templ) {
        var compiled = this.template(templ);
        compiled.render = function (ctx) {
            return this(ctx);
        }
        return compiled;
    }
})(window._);
```

I got this from **Alan Greenblatt**. The link is: http://blattchat.com/2013/06/04/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-js-with-underscore-js-tutorial. His twitter typeahead examples are dated in that they were made for twitter typeahead version 0.9.3 which lacks bloodhound.js. However, it does provide a nice compile function for underscore templating engine.

Now, using **underscore templating**, the code will look like:

```
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'twitter-oss',
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: repos.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    suggestion: _.compile([
      '<p class="repo-language"><%=language%></p>',
      '<p class="repo-name"><%=name%></p>',
      '<p class="repo-description"><%=description%></p>'
    ].join(''))
  }
});
```

Comment: It seems that just using `_.template()` works as well.

Comment: @luwes: Thanks for the info. Do you have a jsFiddle handy?

Comment: Not right away, sorry. It's just `suggestion: _.template(`. They both return functions anyway, typeahead won't see a difference between **_.compile** and **_.template**. Cheers

Comment: Any idea how to get it to work with Hogan?  I tried `Hogan.compile(...)` but that doesn't work.  If you have a solution please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727534/migrating-to-typeahead-0-10-with-hogan -- Thx!

Comment: Is there an example using knockoutjs templates?

Answer (score 11):

The good news is that as stated by Steve Pavarno you don't need a template engine anymore. You can achieve the desired result by passing a function like so:

```
// ...
templates: {
    suggestion: function(data) { // data is an object as returned by suggestion engine
        return '<div class="tt-suggest-page">' + data.value + '</div>';
    };
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is way more useful than using the template engine.